# JetBrains Upsource постоянный Disconnected. Где хранятся логи?

Tags: linux, docker, jetbrains

Развернул Upsource Build 2017.3.2888 с Docker образа.

При настройке указал, что Hub будет внутренний.

VOLUME не прописывал.

То есть ему некуда подключаться. Права на папки должны быть. Все на образе. Куда он пытается подключаться?
Где посмотреть логи? Я не смог найти чего-то полезного.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась не на стороне сервера, а на стороне клиента.
Подключение шло через прокси. Нужно внести адрес сервера в исключения прокси.